# CSS - Images and Footer Problems

Tags: css, image, footer

Ok, if you go here:  http://opportunityfinance.net/Test/2013conf/index.html

You will notice 2 layout issues

[image: Problem 1 - Images need to be below GOLD]

This image of the 3 logos needs to be below the "Gold" `<h4>` tag.  But for some reason it won't do it.  I have assigned the `<div>` tag a position of `relative` since there are other divs within it that need to align the images to the bottom, and this does it correctly, however, it now won't go below the `<h4>Gold</h4>` HTML.

Next Layout issue:

[image: Footer is cutting off the body content]

I have been trying like hell to get a footer on the bottom of the page.  Sounds simple right?  WRONG!  But now that I got the div to be at the bottom, it seems to be cutting off the top area divs above it.  So, not all of the content is showing.  Instead it is being pushed underneath of the footer.  How can I fix this?  Tried to put a padding on it, but now sure where and/or how?  margin-top on the footer doesn't seem to do anything either.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  I have been struggling like hell to get this simple layout in order.  It should be a fluid layout, as I'm resizing text down as the page resizes also, which seems to be perfectly fine, except for these 2 problems :(

***EDIT***

Here is a pic of what it looks like when applying the container div a 100 pixel height value:

[image: div with 100 pixel height]

It is giving it too much space between the `<h4>Gold</h4>` and the 3 images.  Atleast this is the case in Opera.  Any possible work-arounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a fix for one

```
.body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2em 2em 52px 0;
}
```

you have 3 logo's in one div, on that div add a height, for example

```
element.style {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Pretty basic stuff really, you should look into `clearfix's` here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

When you add a `float` or `position:absolute;` to a div,  in a way it gives up its `reserved` space so that causes the parent `div` to think that there isnt anything inside and therefor has no `height`, `clearfix` will fix these problems for you, reason i say is becuase the 3 logo's are all either `floated` or `absolute;`

this is the `result` i get

[image]

Comment: Clearfix is the solution for containers of floating elements but nothing will do the same for absolutely (and fixed) positioned elements because they're completely out of the flow. You've to know where they are, how much space they can occupy (even with 200% of zoom text according to WCAG 2.0) and leave room for that. Can be a margin or padding along an element blocking others to display there, etc

Comment: Yes, the only reason i suggested clearfix is becuase he has both floated and absolute so the floated will gain most the height back, but yeah thanks for the info

Comment: I tried setting the height to 100 pixels just now... and it's too far down.  How come?

Comment: I just went to your link, and it looks fine on my screen, send me a pic if you can :)

Comment: Look at it in Opera Browsers...  Will update my question with a new pic of the way it looks now.

Comment: @Connor - Just updated my question.  Please have a look in Opera Browser, gonna see how it looks now in other browsers.  And Thanks :)

Comment: Also, it can't add a height in pixels, because when you make is SMALLER, the 100 pixels stays that way, yet the images shrink down, creating a HUGE GAP between the images and the Gold Header.

Comment: i have just looked in all opera browsers and they all look fine, it must be something else?

Comment: And unless you can think of another solution instead of adding a height then your pretty much screwed :)

Comment: Well, I'm using Opera 12.14 (latest version), with 1024 screen width by 600 pixel screen height (on a notebook).  BTW, looks good initially in all other browsers, but when you resize it down, the GAP appears.... argg!

Comment: Oh, i can see that it has a gap now i re-size the page, but you have a lot of work to do on smaller screens anyway because i cant barely read anything when i make it smaller, if you make the content bigger on smaller screens the gap might go away

Comment: I think it works great for cell phones though, it's supposed to resize the text down when it gets smaller so as to keep the layout INTACT.

Comment: Also, I fixed the problem using jQuery and adding the height to be resized according to the biggest image (which is the wells fargo image).  Ofcourse, images need a complete overhaul IMHO.  But that's not my area.

Comment: Glad to help, the site does look great i will admit, the Typography makes everything :) Good Luck